# Using xdebug with Netbeans on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I want to use xdebug with my netbeans on Ubuntu 16.04. I have php 7 running, phpinfo shows

```
xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version     2.4.1
IDE Key     netbeans-xdebug
Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol     $Revision: 1.145 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

edit: I now added `xdebug.remote_autostart = on` to my php.ini, and netbeans now seems to talk to xdebug, it says `xdebug-netbeans running`. Hooray. But still, I have the problem that xdebug does not stop at breakpoints, and it doesnt show my any data in the netbeans windows.

Comment: I also faced the same issue with Netbeans in Ubuntu 16.04. So, now I am using Eclipse PDT. It's working perfectly. Every one facing this awful problem (or bug) in Netbeans with Xdebug.